# Online references for creating advanced macros?

Tags: macros, documentation, online, learning

I am looking for online references for creating advanced macros for LaTeX.

Comment: A tongue-in-cheek comment: [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is a good online reference. `;)`

Answer (score 5):

I would say one good starting point for something online is Victor Eijkhout's [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic). It is freely available. As mentioned on the [TeX FAQ entry on ol' books](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ol-books), "it’s not a beginner’s tutorial but it’s a fine reference."

This does not actually count as an online reference, per se, but it is a (free) reference none the less.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not really a book, the source documentation for LaTeX is also a good resource for all sorts of TeX programming techniques.  You can access it with `texdoc source2e`. Between that and TeX by Topic, you can learn an awful lot.

Comment: At least in TeXlive 2011, TeX by topic topic is also available via `texdoc`: `texdoc texbytopic`.

Answer (score 2):

(I think the answers should be community wiki)

- I sometimes use the [TeX Primitive Control Sequences](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html)